# Passing View based on drawables to ImageView

Tags: android, gridview, imageview, drawable

I've got something like this:
`view = gridView.getChildAt(position)`

All elements in gridView are drawables stored in drawable folder
Now my question:
How to pass view to imageView or how to get resourceId from view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html) tutorial should have everything you need, the only difference is, that you need to pass in the item at `gridView.getChildAt(position)` rather then all the items in the gridView as in this tutorial

you would want to do something like

```
 imageView.setImageResource(gridView.getChildAt(position))
```

but without seeing your code i cannot put up the correct answer, but looking at the tutorial that i have added, you would add code like above to get want you want